# How to say that something happens in the future related to a particular date?

Tags: time, future-time

How to say that something happens in the future related to a particular date?

> Fines are issued in the future *??? as related to the date of first missed payment ???*

Comment: You can say "Fines are issued 5(/6/7/...) days(/weeks/...) following/after the day/date of the first missed payment."

Comment: **Penalties are imposed** is a more appropriate expression for a finance agreement: a fine normally relates to breaking the law, where a penalty can also be used about a breach of some financial rule. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/penalty

Answer (score 3):

To specify a particular date the prepostion "on" is usually used

> Failure to receive payment will result in fines **on** or after the 20th of the month.
>   Your assignments are due **on** August 30th.

"On" is used to designate a specific time, "by" may be used to signify the time before and including the "on" time, "after" would be used for any time post the "on" time.

> Our meeting is on the 10th.
>   The meeting presentation needs to be finished by the 9th.
>   After the 10th, it will be too late.

Comment: @SovereignSun +1  Typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

One of my credit card bills contains this verbiage:

> **Late Payment Warning:** If we do not receive your Total Minimum Payment by the date listed above, you may have to pay a late fee of up to $37.00 and your APRs may be increased up to the Penalty APR of 29.99%.

I would use something like that (or exactly that) for my contract, were I drafting one.